# where will the content of echo be displayed when to run php backend way?

Tags: php, backend

```
<?php    
    echo "i am here";    
?>
```

For the simple code,
"i am here" will be displayed on web when to run on browser ,
"i am here" will be displayed on console when to run  interactively.

What will happen when to run the code on my vps backend way?
I set an crontab task on my vps machine to run the code,where will "i am here" be displayed when time is coming?

Comment: it writes to `stdout`

Comment: What do you mean by "backend way"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

It will be written to your STDOUT channel.
According to how your crontab is configured, you'll will or will not see this message.
Crontab output can be send to the void (/dev/null), but can also be mailed to you, or can be in a log.

This has nothing to do with PHP, but with your cron config.